# composite indexes in sqlite

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

My table consists of 104856 rows, having 13 columns.
The schema of the table is as follows:

```
public static final class Vehicle4Wheel implements BaseColumns{
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="Vehicle4Wheel";
    public static final String VEH_ID = "VEH_ID";
    public static final String VEH_REG_NUM = "VEH_REG_NUM";
    public static final String VEH_ENGINE_NO = "VEH_ENGINE_NO";
    public static final String VEH_CHASIS_NO= "VEH_CHASIS_NO";
    public static final String VEH_MAKE= "VEH_MAKE";
    public static final String VEH_MAKE_MODEL= "VEH_MAKE_MODEL";
    public static final String VEH_COLOR = "VEH_COLOR";
    public static final String VEH_MODEL = "VEH_MODEL";
    public static final String VEH_CC = "VEH_CC";
    public static final String OWN_NAME = "OWN_NAME";
    public static final String OWN_FNAME = "OWN_FNAME";
    public static final String CNIC = "OWN_CNIC";
    public static final String OWN_ADDRESS = "OWN_ADDRESS";
}
```

I want to search for data using VEH_REG_NUM, VEH_ENGINE_NO, VEH_CHASIS_NO.
For faster search in the table, I have created a composite index. The index query is as follow:

```
String indexVeh4Wheel = "CREATE INDEX veh4wheel_search ON Vehicle4Wheel(VEH_REG_NUM, VEH_ENGINE_NO, VEH_CHASIS_NO)";
```

When I search for data using VEH_REG_NUM, the search is fast.
When I search for data using VEH_ENGINE_NO and VEH_CHASIS_NO, the search is slow.

Do I need to make a separate index for each column for the faster result?
Like,

```
String indexVeh4reg = "CREATE INDEX veh4wheel_reg ON 
                       Vehicle4Wheel(VEH_REG_NUM)";
String indexVeh4eng = "CREATE INDEX veh4wheel_eng ON 
                       Vehicle4Wheel(VEH_ENGINE_NO)";
String indexVeh4chass = "CREATE INDEX veh4wheel_chass ON 
                         Vehicle4Wheel(VEH_CHASIS_NO)";
```

Comment: YES, of course. Each field must be individually indexed. You want all of your **WHERE** and your **JOIN** fields indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: yes.

DB indices are lists* of references to rows, sorted by whatever columns you give while creating the index. The sorting works the same as in "order by" - latter criteria are only taken into account if all the former are not decisive. In your case, unless you have multiple vehicles with the same registration number, the two other columns will never be used.

And even if they were, that would not speed up your search: imagine a list of people sorted by last name, and then the first name. It would be very useful for two types of searches:

- finding people with the same last name
- finding people with specific first name and last name

But it would not help you much in searches for people with specific first name. You would need to browse all the list anyway, because the first names, unlike the last names, would never be clustered together.